# Can't ping from gnome extensions

Tags: linux, networking, fedora, ping, gnome

I'm running GNOME Shell 3.36.7 on Fedora 32.

I have the following gnome extensions that would display `ping` status (I have the most recent versions installed from extensions.gnome.org, and I only run one at a time):

- https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1155/iconping-for-gnome/
- https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/923/ping-indicator/
- https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1607/ping-monitor/

They have all stopped working *at the same time*, whereas I can run `ping` from the CLI just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Fedora 32 (Fedora Workstation Live x86_64 32.1-6) on a VM and, initially, the extension runs fine both on GNOME Shell 3.36.1 and after upgrading to GNOME 3.36.7. However, running a full `dnf update` results in unresponsive extensions.

I repeated the test, upgrading one package at a time, and turns out the issue arises from upgrading `iputils` from version `20190515-5.fc32` to `20200821-1.fc32`. Running `dnf downgrade iputils` makes the extensions work again.